# What is difference between Unipartite Secret Construction, Bipartite Secret Construction and Multipartite Secret Construction

Tags: secret-sharing

In this [paper](http://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/440d/fa8ab99301d4ea3a8b19c0748575915aef15.pdf) authors  extend Asmuth–Bloom and Kaya schemes to
bipartite access structures and further investigate how SSSs realizing multipartite access structures can be conducted with the CRT.

The authors, also, written  Secret Construction  **procedure is same** in    Unipartite  Secret Construction, Bipartite Secret Construction and Multipartite Secret Construction.

**Unipartite(Asmuth–Bloom) Secret Construction**

> Assume $C$ is a coalition of $t$ participants to construct the secret.
>   Let $M_C =\prod_{i=1}^{C}m_i$  $y ≡ y_ i \mod m_ i $
>
> for $i ∈ C$, solve y in $GF(M_C  )$ uniquely using the CRT.   Compute
>   the secret as
>        K = y mod p
>
> According to the CRT, y can be determined uniquely in $GF(M_ C)$ .
>   Since $y < M ≤ M_C$ , the solution is also unique in $GF(M)$.

**Bipartite Secret Construction:**

> Assume $C$ is a coalition of $\tau$ participants to construct the
>   secret.  Let $M_C =\prod_{f(y_i) ∈  C}m_i$
>
> $y \equiv y_i \mod m_ i $
>
> for $f(y_i) ∈ C$, solve y in $GF(M_C  )$ uniquely using the CRT.
>   Compute the secret as 
>         K = y mod p

**Multipartite Secret Construction**

> Assume $C$ is a coalition of $\tau$ participants to construct the
>   secret. Let $M_C =\prod_{f(y_i) ∈  C}m_i$
>
> $y \equiv y_i \mod m_ i$
>
> for $f(y_i) ∈ C$, solve y in $GF(M_C)$ uniquely using the CRT.
>
> Compute the secret as
>         K = y mod p

I am getting confusion regarding the difference between Unipartite Secret Construction, Bipartite Secret Construction and Multipartite Secret Construction to .

Could you please explain the intuitive *difference* between Unipartite Secret Construction, Bipartite Secret Construction, and Multipartite Secret Construction.